# Minted: colorize variable in inline mode

Tags: color, minted, code

Is it possible to specify how to color a variable with `mintinline`? What I mean is, for instance, to use `\mintinline{python}{myClass}` and color `myClass` as a Class variable, or as a function. If I use the command as it is, I just get black color by default, but strings are colorized correctly, like `\mintinline{python}{'a string'}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.  To start with your mark-up must convey to Pygments the info that `myClass` is a class object name.  Perhaps while registering a dedicated lexer with Pygments which will simply tokenize every word in the input as a class name.  Meanwhile, you can do some reverse-engineering and produce for example this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\highlightaspyclass[1]{%
  \minted@generate@PYGdef{default}%
  {\minted@PYGdef@default\PYG{n+nc}{#1}}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is highlighted \highlightaspyclass{myClass}.
\end{document}
```

Basically for this I started from some

```latex
\begin{minted}{python}
class myClass:
    pass
\end{minted}
```

in the document, ran latex and went to see the pygmentize output mark-up which turned out to be `\PYG{n+nc}{myClass}` which will thus a priori the mark-up for Python Class objects which I could abstract into a sort of generic `\highlightaspyclass` command.

Then some digging into minted source code and by luck it was possible to do the above.  "default" stands for the "style" variable defined via `\usemintedstyle`, so update the above if using a custom one. (section `3.4 Using different styles` in the minted doc).

You will need to repeat the above preliminary procedure for each other type of token and create an associated custom macro.

Mind that things such as compatibility with being used in section titles or the like might get lost and perhaps handling of special characters requiring sanitization that `\mintedinline` does in its way and is not done in our custom hacked command.

You must run the above with shell-escape, as generally with minted.

[image: minted example]

EDIT: you will also have to set manually the typeface, like for example using monospace font family which I have not done here.